# Calling a function from another function within the same prototype and context of this

Tags: javascript, bind, prototype

In attempting to keep with the DRY principle, I decided to revise a function's prototype in an effort to reduce the number of function.call() calls.

Following is a snippet of what I currently have and further clarification as to what I am attempting to do.

```
com.domain.$ = function(s){
     if(!this){return new com.domain.$(s);}

    this.selector = s;
    this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(s);
}

com.domain.$.prototype = (function(){
    function exe(f){
        var e = this.elements,
            el = e.length;
        for(var i=0; i<el; i++){
            f(e[i]);
        }
    }

    function addClass(c){exe.call(this,function(el){el.classList.add(c);});}
    function removeClass(c){exe.call(this,function(el){el.classList.remove(c);});}
    function toggleClass(c){exe.call(this,function(el){el.classList.toggle(c);});}

    return {
        addClass:addClass,
        removeClass:removeClass,
        toggleClass:toggleClass
    }
}());
```

I realize this looks very much like I am attempting to mimic the functionality of jQuery. While intentional, this is not meant to act as a replacement but rather a better personal understanding of JavaScript.

That said, what I would like to do is remove the need to invoke `exe()` via `exe.call(this[, fnc]);` in order for the context of `this` to be what I want. I believe I can do this through function binding (`.bind()`), though perhaps not the way I would like to. I understand it is possible to instead do something like:

```
com.domain.$.prototype.exe = function(){}
```

and call it like:

```
function addClass(c){this.exe(function(){});}
```

In doing so, however, I lose the private visibility of `exe()` provided by the closure in my original code. I would like to keep that in tact, if possible.

My question, then, is whether or not it is possible to bind `exe()` within my original code in such a way that I can reduce the redundant use of `exe.call(this`, possess the correct context for `this` within `exe()`, and maintain the private visibility within the closure?

If this seems a poor implementation of what I am trying to accomplish, I am more than happy to consider other options.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, since at the moment you define `exe()`, the instance you want to call `exe()` on does not exist yet.

In fact, if you are going to make several calls to `com.domain.$`, you will use `exe()` with different instances and therefore it does not make sense to bind `exe()` to a *specific* instance.

If you wanted to do that, you'd have to define all these methods inside the constructor and you would loose all the advantages of prototypes:

```
(function() {
    function exe(f){
        // ...
    }

    com.domain.$ = function(s){
        // ...

        var exe_ = exe.bind(this);
        this.addClass = function(c) {
             exe_(function(el){el.classList.add(c);});
        };
        // ...
    };
}());
```

I would suggest, if you don't want to use `.call`, to just modify `exe()` so that it accepts an array of elements as argument and pass `this.elements` to it from the prototype functions. I don't see why `exe()` needs to use `this` at all. It's merely a helper which passes each element of an array to a given function and by making it more general, it is easier to reuse.
For example:

```
var com.domain.$ = (function(o) {
    function exe(arr, f){
        var el = e.length;
        for(var i=0; i<el; i++){
            f(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    var $ = function(s){
         // ...
    }

    $.prototype.addClass = function(c){
        exe(this.elements, function(el){
            el.classList.add(c);
        });
    };
    // ... 

    return $;
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Felix.

As you noticed, I want to keep the functionality out of the definition of the constructor for obvious reasons.

As you also noted, I could pass `this.elements` to `exe()`, and I did consider this, but I was hoping to avoid redundantly using `exe(this.elements, ...` and keep the script file smaller.

Comment: Some things are just not possible :) You should rather focus on readability and maintainability and use a code minifier to reduce the file size.